# C#: File.Delete() issues in .exe

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that needs to delete multiple .zip files. It works as intended when I run from Visual Studio, the issue is when I compiled it into .exe format. For anything more than 2 zip files the executable will stop & exit on the 3rd file, and additionally the .exe vanishes from the bin\debug directory I was running it from.

Here's a short program outlining what I'm trying to do, gives the same results on my machine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeleteMultipleFilesFromDirectory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dir = "C:\\ZipDirectory\\DeleteZipFiles\\";
            Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*.zip").ToList().ForEach(s => File.Delete(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: I would just put this in a try catch, and log it to some file on your system to see if any errors?

Comment: Are you running as admin?

Comment: No errors/exceptions are being thrown. Tried catching and nothing was caught. Tried Console.WriteLine() for the files to make sure the .exe wasn't in the list as well.

Comment: @StrangeGraphs has a good point, are you running as admin?

Comment: Pretty sure your anti virus is worried about a potential ransom-ware..

Comment: Same behavior when running as Administrator.

Comment: Could this be proof of ghosts? maybe anti-virus, but maybe ghosts?

Comment: can you check eventvwr for any errors logged during the run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the executable is vanishing from the machine I assume that your antivirus software is deleting it, since deleting lots of files is a potential danger.

A possible fix is adding it to the application whitelist of your antivirus software.

Comment: *absolutely clear* sounds exagerated. Any reference confirming this behavior? Never heard about it and i'm sure i've deleted a bunch of file as a developer..

Comment: @sam you are right. Since I have faced the same problems with Avast and Norton, I exagerated a bit. It just seems to me that it is the most obvious thing.

Comment: I agree that this is the most likely candidate. A number of the most popular (if not all the mainstream) AV software detects *behavior* on top of the standard signature detection. It's possible that OP's program, being unsigned and untrusted, could be tripping this behavior. I've certainly had it happen a few times.

Comment: @Wolle - you hit the nail on the head. The antivirus was catching and quarantining. Thank you very much for the help! I'm having our sysadmin add the executable directory to the antivirus' whitelist.